# Who first proved that the spectrum of an operator is contained in the closure of its numerical range?

Tags: mathematics, functional-analysis

We have recently proven in our functional analysis II lecture that the spectrum of an operator is contained in the closure of its numerical range.
On the German wikipedia [page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerischer_Wertebereich#Versionen_f%C3%BCr_Operatoren) for the numerical radius they say that Otto Toeplitz already investigated the numerical range in 1918.
But who has proven this result (first)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the spectral inclusion theorem. Toeplitz's 1918 paper [Das algebraische Analogon zu einem Satze von Fejér](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01212904) already has it for finite dimensional operators as Satz 4. This was before the language of operators and Hilbert spaces introduced by von Neumann in 1927-29, see [Highlights in the History of Spectral Theory by Steen](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319079), so it is phrased in terms of eigenvalues and bilinear forms:

> "*Die Eigenwerte einer beliebigen Bilinearform C gehoren alle zu ihrem Wertvorrat*". [The eigenvalues of any bilinear form belong to its value range.]

According to [Gustafson and Rao's Numerical Range, p.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=ICfoBwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s), for bounded operators in Hilbert space the theorem was first proved by [Wintner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurel_Wintner) in [Zur Theorie der beschränkten Bilinearformen (1929)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01187766), who has spectrum and Hilbert spaces, but does not use the term "operator" either. For unbounded operators, the spectral inclusion is false. [Stone in Linear Transformations in Hilbert Space (1932)](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Transformations_in_Hilbert_Space.html?id=uebNAwAAQBAJ) mentions that for normal operators the closure of the numerical range is the convex hull of the spectrum. A generalization to non-linear operators is due to [Zarantonello (1967)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102992107).

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Gustafson and Rao call it that in their monograph. If you google "numerical range spectral inclusion" top results are on point.